# How to get the size of my organization repositories?

Tags: github, repository, github-organizations

I am admin of a Github Organization and my storage is higher than the limit.

[image: Storage limit]

That's why I want to find the repositories that take the most storage and apply a fix.

The only way I found was clicking my avatar (top right) => Settings => Repositories.
And here, I can see the size of them.

[image: Repositories by size]

However, this is only the repositories I HAVE PARTICIPATED IN, not all the repositories from my organization. So I tried to find the same page as my Organization but does not exists.

[image: Not the same page as Organization]

**My question is : What is the easiest way to get the list of my organization's repositories by size ?**

Thank you

Comment: I have this very same question. I tried adding myself as a member of my own repositories (if that makes sense). But no joy ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the GitHub CLI, you can get the name and size in KB of the repos within the organization:

```bash
gh repo list <my_org> --limit 999 --json name,diskUsage
```

Answer (score 2):

The following might be handy to view the size in MBs

```bash
$ gh repo list <org_name> --limit 999 --json name,diskUsage | jq '.[] | .diskUsage = (.diskUsage / 1024) | {name: .name, diskUsage: .diskUsage}'
```

Comment: add ' please at the end

Answer (score 2):

Or you can get a single repository size:

`gh repo view <org>/<repo> --json diskUsage`